# android ndk hw debuggning memory

Tags: memory-management, android-studio, android-ndk, remote-debugging, compiler-optimization

### Backgrond

I am very experienced in C and pretty new to Android and Java, but this is rather environmental issues that programming.

I have developed an administrative application in ANSI-C to be ported to any OS, just adding a UI in OS-dependent code. Well it uses quite some memory, especially for huge user files. I have a working Win32 program, trying to make an Android app using Android Studio with NDK.

### Android studio bundle NDK installation works fine

I have installed and made a Win7 ultimate Android Studio 1.3 with bundle NDK and made compiling and running the ActionbarStyled (non NDK) hello-jni (NDK) sample in the emulators, smooth and nice. I also in the emulator been successfully running Hello-jni sample with a bunch of extra c-files (not called, at present just garbage, compiled without errors, in this step)

Then I tried to connect my Samsung TAB3 SM-T110 template (one need a Win7 Samsung driver SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.zip) to my Win7 and tried it. ActionbarStyled sample works just fine. So does the Hello-JNI sample.

## But

Running Hello-jni sample with a bunch of extra c-files I get this error message: 
Error while starting native debug session: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find process for com.example.hellojni on device samsung-sm_t110-47900bc50c0c3100

I try to understand what is the issue? Is it lack of memory, the Samsung is full of active running apps, the emulator obviously not.

What makes the Samsung unit to halt the application? Error message is not that describing?

### Some more questions supporting handling this kind of issues

We are talking about Android studio 1.3 bundle NDK, how much from earlier setups (in articles) are applicable for this new future NDK standard use?

### Memory?

Running the pure Hello-jni sample I have about 6Mb memory (where 5Mb are used), that is pretty poor for my needs, is there something I need to do have my app getting more memory allocated? Is the error message due to running out of memory?

How large Android Apps are possible to do? Are we in a world like the 8-bit DOS 64Kb segment business again? I know it from past but that isen't the case? And if need to know to handle it. The  [Library for unrestricted heap memory for bitmaps using NDK on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041326/library-for-unrestricted-heap-memory-for-bitmaps-using-ndk-on-android) question is interesting to read, but here we are talking about the jni (C-)code rather than java.

### Compiler optimisation?

I have some really huge C-files due to that they are machine generated converting an XML library of documents to C-code (made a program writing C-code from the XSD definitions). In an application I most of the time use only say 5% of all the C-function, the rest are in Windows dev studio/compiler optimised away. Certainly I can reorganise my source code to quite some extra work, but I need to know. How is the optimisation in the Android Studio NDK support?

Thing is in this test no extra C-functions are called except the same regular as in the hello-jni sample. Actually the compiler should make exactly the same in both cases (the modified and the original hello-jni). But obviously it don't. Please explain a bit more how the environment works so I know?

### General interest

I tried to find any spot in the Android developers that describe things like compiler behaviour, memory management and environment (the Java handles such completely different, but in C-programming on need to be aware). I think for NDK use it would be interesting getting a good answer here, for the general understanding of the environment, somewhere in the Android developer pages, rather than here. That also includes how the compiler optimises in different situations. But also how to make environmental settings.

Comment: _"How is the optimisation in the Android Studio NDK support?"_ I'm assuming you're talking about C/C++ code optimization. The NDK (as of R10e) includes Clang 3.6 and GCC 4.9 (you can choose which of them you want to use). I don't know how they compare to Microsoft's compiler, but you can probably find some benchmarks somewhere.

Comment: Yes I am talking about C-code. Well, of course I am used to the MS dev systems, but the issue is to understand rather than to have it the MS way. Your reply helps by getting me Google search tags, but are there any general documentation of the NDK behaviour?

Comment: Well I am constantly digging in the pit of Android and learning a lot. I am not here to judge, and Android is an OSP and MSVS is indeed a commercial SW and the culture is completely different. When I am a bit further I believe my contribution is writing it, a more general understand NDK documentation for new immigrants to the Android environment. Would be nice if some could tell how a project creating a documentation (teamwork like most in Android looks to be)?

Comment: So far for instance I have learned that to make large applications/applications using a lot of memory (like for pictures) it looks like there is a must of C-programming because the Java heap is limited and the JNI heap is told to be unlimited by the system but rather by the HW environment (like usually and pre Windows like always, and swapping kind of sucks so the same in Windows).

Comment: I think Java is nice but as a look alike so extremely different from C. C where everything is hard facts and everything must be done by yourself, but under almost full control (in the DOS age absolute control). Java looks like C and in on the surface looks like C, but Java includes something like the Win32 SDK library 1000 times more. Very little has to be written and in many cases it is surprisingly simple to make an app (the user interface) and very smooth. The problem for a C-programmer is you are not alone driving the car and understand what the Java guy is doing. If you do it's smooth.

Comment: Well the actual case is that I have written a program to convert a large library of xsd for XML handling of a standard organisation into C-functions and data structures etc for reading writing etc the XML code from C-programs. This ends according to MSVC to 955 functions (have a Win32 app made and now making an Android NDK app with the same use and behaviour. Well in my app I use I would believe about 100 of the 955 and the MSVC x64 release version is 1169kb

Comment: The reason it is not 10Mb is that the MSVC skips the 850 unused functions by the linker optimisation. The Android case we are talking about a NDK library that the Java app uses and if I do a MSVC DLL there will not be a linker optimisation and the DLL will be huge? (haven't tried that) I assume the reason the Samsung units fails and the HAXM works (makes a remark it increased the memory however) is that the NDK library I make is too huge for the Samsung unit to load. But I don't know if my assumption is right? I guess I have to make some tests, removing the 850 functions?

Comment: Well, I tried to solve this by making a c static lib-file from where I get the C-functions used (and the others are that way not included) in the dynamic JNI library I use in my Android app. Should be an easy thing I thought. However the JNI is not used as a C-programming work bench but as a system to add features to the Java environment. Making a static JNI lib with the Android studio is really hard to find out. Not much easier how to use. I think I have to use #ifdef XXX to manually filter what the linker should perform. Bit sad. If anyone knows how to instruct how to do a static lib, tell.