# OutOfMemoryError although I'm down scale the bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, out-of-memory, android-resources

I use small resource images (max 25kb, max 256x256) and load some larger images from the internet with picasso. The picasso loading never failed until now. But the resource image loading does sometimes.

For the resource images I use the code appended (`setBitmap`), but although I down scale the images, on some devices my app still produces a `OutOfMemoryError` when calling `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`. Does anyone have an idea, where to look next?

```
private static void setBitmap(final ImageView iv, final int resId)
{
    iv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()
    {
        public boolean onPreDraw()
        {
            iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            iv.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(iv.getContext().getResources(), resId, iv.getMeasuredWidth(), iv.getMeasuredHeight()));
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int w, int h)
{
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, w, h);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int w, int h)
{
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > h || width > w)
    {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > h && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > w)
        {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    L.d(ImageTools.class, "inSampleSize | height | width: " + inSampleSize + " | " + height + " | " + width);

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list ImageViews you could implement a cache:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: that's what I have and that's, now that you say it, makes sense... I knew about the cache and the link, but somehow dind't think I need it, because I only use a few small images... But your "if you have a listview" made me think now and you're right...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest as your last option. 
However I do not recommend this to be use because it can make your app slow.

Answer (score 0):

you can request for more `memory` by using

> ```
>  android:largeHeap="true"
> ```

in the manifest.

also, you can use native memory (NDK & JNI) , so you actually bypass the heap size limitation.

here are some posts made about it:

- [How to cache bitmaps into native memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900732/how-to-cache-bitmaps-into-native-memory)
- [JNI bitmap operations , for helping to avoid OOM when using large images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250951/jni-bitmap-operations-for-helping-to-avoid-oom-when-using-large-images)

and here's a library made for it:

- https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations

*happy coding*

regards maven