# upload large file (multi-part) using HttpsURLConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to upload a large file using HttpsURLConnection (together with other tokens), if I'm uploading it in one chunk, obviously, I'm getting an OutOfMemory exception.
I tried to follow this example: http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/android-code-to-upload-download-large-files-to-server-2/
But now I'm getting a "I/O error during system call, Broken pipe" error.

I saw that this a known issue, but I didn't find any good solution. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please search for answers before posting question here!         Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk

Comment: Thanks, but i did search and didn't find the answer. please note that my problem is with sending large files, and not with creating multi part request

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public void connectForMultipart() throws Exception {
    con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    con.connect();
    os = con.getOutputStream();
}

public void addFormPart(String paramName, String value) throws Exception {
    writeParamData(paramName, value);
}

public void addFilePart(String paramName, String fileName, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + "\r\n").getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + paramName +  "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write( ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"  ).getBytes());
    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());

    os.write(data);

    os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
}   
public void finishMultipart() throws Exception {
    os.write( (delimiter + boundary + delimiter + "\r\n").getBytes());
}
```

you can request to use more memory by using

> ```
>  android:largeHeap="true"
> ```

in the manifest.

also, you can use native memory (NDK & JNI) , so you actually bypass the heap size limitation.

here are some posts made about it:

- [How to cache bitmaps into native memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900732/how-to-cache-bitmaps-into-native-memory)
- [JNI bitmap operations , for helping to avoid OOM when using large images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250951/jni-bitmap-operations-for-helping-to-avoid-oom-when-using-large-images)

and here's a library made for it:

- https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations

*happy coding*

regards maven

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is with large files, this solution won't solve this... as it uploads the file in one chunk...